# Multiple images in one animation javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

I'm developing a webpage and I would like to create an animation, which images would be different according to the direction it moves. Images would change in the end of right/left screen edge.

I have coded movement of my object, but I have got a problem with swapping images at the edges of the screen.

In the picture, you can see what I've got so far, and what I would like to achieve.

I'm also putting here my code.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>animate demo</title> 
<style>
 div { background: url(bus.png); 
position: absolute; 
left: 0px; 
width: 265px; 
height: 47px; 
margin: 5px; }
 </style> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br> 
<div class="block"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $width = $(window).width();

for($count = 0; $count != 100; $count++){
 for($a=1; $a <= ($width/10); $a++){
 $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=10px" }, 100 );

 } for($a=1; $a <= ($width/10); $a++){
 $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=10px" }, 100 );
 }
 }
 </script>

</body>
 </html>
```

http://i40.tinypic.com/2wg581y.jpg

Let's say that another image will be tram.png

Could anyone help me to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
for ($count = 0; $count != 100; $count++){
  for($a=1; $a <= ($width/10); $a++){
    $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=10px" }, 100 );
  }

  $(".block").css({'backgroundImage': 'tram.png'});

  for($a=1; $a <= ($width/10); $a++){
    $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=10px" }, 100 );
  }
  $(".block").css({'backgroundImage': 'bus.png'});

}
```